# Copia de ultimo archivo en Robocopy

Tags: cmd

Estoy utilizando `robocopy` y tengo una pequeña duda. ¿Alguno sabe como puedo hacer para que me copie los archivos `.rar` pero solamente los que se hayan creado hoy?

Esta es la sentencia que tengo pero no me da resultado:

```
robocopy "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Nueva carpeta" "F:\backup\backupPrueba" /maxage:1:17:00 /e /r:1 /w:1 /mir
```

Comment: ese `maxage` pinta raro. qué es `:17:00`? Prueba con solamente `/maxage:1`  (un día) o con `/maxage:20181228`

Comment: Para solamente .rar, añada *.rar antes de /maxage